# invariant theory for $G\times \text{O}(n)$

Tags: invariant-theory

We know that the invariants of the orthogonal group $\text {O}(n)$ gives us the Brauer algebra. Is there any known results for the invariants of $G\times \text{O}(n)$ acting on the tensor space where $G$ is the finite group ?

Comment: What do you mean when you write "*the* finite group" ? There is a little bit more than one ;-) What action do you have in mind?

Comment: @JohannesHahn, it must be the typical finite group.  So, you know, [a group of order 1024](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/2000-announce.pdf).  :-)  (One could also wonder what "the tensor space" is.)

Comment: @JohannesHahn it's a typical English error (especially for users from a few native tongues). Certainly it's meant "where $G$ is a [some] finite group".